# Repeater to excel with html tags issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, repeater

Hi All I am trying to export my Repeater content into Excel. I have followed this article and everything is working good.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-ASPNet-Repeater-Control-to-Excel-File.aspx

How ever I have small problem. Inside repeater column I have HTML text which splits into multiple rows after export. 
How to export repeater to excel with HTML content into single row and column.

Here is my repeaters output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Abc is Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Email@123.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>
            <h1>Description title</h1>
            <p>Content for description</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contact</td>
                    <td>Value for contact</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Emails goes here</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need description field into single column.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed repeater to Gridview and it is working perfectly. Here is the link I followed:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try use tag `<pre>` or change dataformat before copy to clipboard

Comment: I am not copying any data... I am exporting data using c# code. As described in the article

Comment: never mind, you can do anything before send the content to excel, parse your html content in code and change contant that you wont post in one column (better to cell)